# How to hide check boxes withing a ListView

Tags: android, layout

first of all, let me show you the code I have in order to do what the title says.

But before, this is how the actitivy looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I70b2.jpg

Ignore the buttons, already managed to hide both of them, only check boxes in each row are left.

My activity layout (the one in the screenshot) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="registrarAsistencia"
        android:text="Registrar Asistencia" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaAlumnos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="376dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.29" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChecarBoxes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="seleccionarTodosNinguno"
        android:text="Seleccionar / Deseleccionar todo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here it is the layout for the list's contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:textSize="16sp" 
          android:textStyle="bold"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/rowTextView2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:textSize="16sp" 
          android:textStyle="italic"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/CheckBox01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:padding="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I mentioned before that the buttons and check boxes needs to be hidden, this will happen ONLY if certain conditions are met.

I have added to the list view a setOnItemClickListener, which contains the following code:

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id) {
                    final Alumno Alumno = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                if(!verEstadisticas){                   
                    Alumno.toggleChecked();         
                    Toast.makeText(AlumnosAsistencia.this, Alumno.getNoControl() + " " + Alumno.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    final AlumnoViewHolder viewHolder = (AlumnoViewHolder) item.getTag();
                    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(Alumno.isChecked());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {             
                            viewHolder.getCheckBox().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                }else{                      
                    // Here Im supposed to do something else, but check boxes needs to be hidden
                }               
            }
        });
```

This is the code for AlumnoViewHolder:

```
class AlumnoViewHolder {
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;

    public AlumnoViewHolder() {
    }

    public AlumnoViewHolder(TextView textView1, TextView textView2, CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
        this.textView1 = textView1;
        this.textView2 = textView2;
    }

    public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }

    public TextView getTextView1() {
        return textView1;
    }

    public void setTextView1(TextView textView1) {
        this.textView1 = textView1;
    }

    public TextView getTextView2() {
        return textView2;
    }

    public void setTextView2(TextView textView2) {
        this.textView2 = textView2;
    }
}
```

As you can see I can hide check boxes only by clicking its row, where I get the View item parameter and the item.getTag() method, however, I cant find a way to do this outside of the onItemClick method. I Googled for solutions and found this:

```
for(int i=0; i < mainListView.getCount(); i++){
                        RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) mainListView.getChildAt(i);
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                        cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
```

However, It didnt work.

Also, I have other minor issue. In the screenshot you can see the activity. Now, if I check a check box and then scroll down, "moving" the check box outside of the screen, and then scroll up to that check box again, the check box would be unchecked, meaning that it didnt save it's status. How can I make sure that it "remembers" its status once it is outside of the screen?

Excuse my english and way to explain things, haha.

Would appreciate all the help possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of doing it in `onItemClick`, you should consider storing the visual state of check boxes into an array(true/false) and use the array in the `getView` of the adapter. Consider this:

```
// Click check box row #1 => suppose to be hidden => set state hidden of check box #1 in the array = true
```

// in getView

```
if(checkbox_visual_state_array[data_position] == true){
  holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
  holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, Im already saving the states of the check boxes (true, false) on an array. However, I dont want to only hide the checked nor unchecked ones, I want to hide ALL of them as just as the activity starts, only if certain conditions are met. See, the first case is the activity with both buttons and all check boxes visibles. In the menu, I can select, lets call it the second case, where I will hide both buttons and ALL check boxes, because I dont need them. In the second case, I only need to click on the row to show some of the data stored on that row clicked. Hope I explained myself.

Comment: I appreciate the help by the way, didnt have more space in previous comment haha.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue of remembering the check box state. You will have to manage it yourself. You need to store the state of each check box. You will then have to update getView() method of your custom adapter to set the state of check box when returning the view. If you are not using custom adapter, then create custom adapter and override the getView method.

Comment: Already stored the state (true or false) of each check box in an array. But I dont know how to do it so the visually state of each box is saved after scrolling them out of the screen.

Comment: You are storing the state. Are you using simple ArrayAdapter for your list? You will have to write your own adapter by extending the ArrayAdapter. You can look at this tutorial on writing your own adapters http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter